# Swift 2 - Xcode 7.0 Cannot Access HTTPS site with unstrusted SSL Certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, swift2, ios9, xcode7

Experts, I'm a Beginner in IOS 9 / XCODE 7 / Swift 2 Development Kit

I'm trying to create an ios app that simply route to Web Application in HTTPS protocol. Below is my code so far in `ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!

    /**
     * Function to Display the Web Application initial URL
     */
    func loadAppURL(){
        let siteAddress = "https://domain:8443/path/to/page"
        let url = NSURL (string: siteAddress)
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAppURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

While Building my App it shows the below Error Message

> 2015-10-01 01:05:13.879 Web Page Tester[2947:31838]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)

and if i try building my app instead of "https://domain:8443/path/to/page" with "http://www.apple.com" its works fine.

I can access my web application in Safari and it asks for accepting the security risks. and i accept it and i can access my Application.

Guide me to fix my issues, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365774/how-to-call-https-url-in-uiwebview/20789128#20789128 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858674/allow-unverified-ssl-certificate-in-uiwebview

Comment: @jrc The question you mentioned is not ios 9 specific and the solution is not in swift also, any other clue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I fixed it

Xcode will reject un-trusted self signed certificates from servers by default.

we can  override this Using `NSURLConnection` and can communicate with a self-signed server, since we have the ability to control the authentication through the additional delegate methods which are not available to a UIWebView. So using `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` we can authenticate against the self signed server.

References 
[NSURLAuthenticationChallenge Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLAuthenticationChallenge_Class/) , @Lilo Lu's [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047132/how-to-call-https-url-in-uiwebview-swift)

I Resolved My Issue in below steps 
**Step 1 :** Defined a `NSURLConnection` in `viewDidLoad()` method of my viewController.swift as follows

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let siteAddress = "https://domain:8443/path/to/page"
    let url = NSURL (string: siteAddress)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let urlConnection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)!
    myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
 }
```

**Step 2 :** used NSURLConnection delegate methods

```
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool{
        print("canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace method Returning True")
        return true
    }


    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge){

        print("did autherntcationchallenge = \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")

        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust  {
            print("send credential Server Trust")
            let credential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
            challenge.sender!.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

        }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic{
            print("send credential HTTP Basic")
            let defaultCredentials: NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
            challenge.sender!.useCredential(defaultCredentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

        }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM{
            print("send credential NTLM")

        } else{
            challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)
      }
}
```

and that worked !!

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was good but you should really consider to stop using forced unwrapping

Comment: and use switch instead of if else blocks.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work for me. Here's the code I used: http://pastebin.com/pd2HFWfy I still get the `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

Comment: Were you able to upload your app successfully on the store ?

Comment: @bhakti123 I didn't tried to upload to app store. I tried it from my phone locally and it was working.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following to your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: I added to code to Info.plist, no change in error, getting the same error as before

Comment: did you make sure that it's a boolean value in a dictionary? Needs to look like the edit I just put

Comment: Yes , Its same as you shown in my Xcode, I will try the solution mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365774/how-to-call-https-url-in-uiwebview/20789128#20789128

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.

Step 1. Add `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to your viewcontroller, to overwrite methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {
```

Step 2. Override viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let siteAddress = "https://mysiteaddress"
        let url = URL(string: siteAddress)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let urlConnection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: urlRequest, delegate: self)!
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
```

Step 3 Overwrite `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` and `didReceive challenge`

```
func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: URLProtectionSpace) -> Bool {
    print("\ncanAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace method Returning True\n")
    return true
}

func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    print("did autherntcationchallenge = \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust  {
        print("\nsend credential Server Trust\n")
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        challenge.sender!.use(credential, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic{
        print("send credential HTTP Basic")
        let defaultCredentials: URLCredential = URLCredential(user: "user", password: "password", persistence:URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender!.use(defaultCredentials, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM{
        print("\nsend credential NTLM\n")

    } else{
        challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandling!(for: challenge)
    }

}
```

Thanks Navas Basheer for the original solution! Saved me a ton of time

Answer (score 0):

1- Create category  "NSURLRequestCategory" -> after import this category to your bridge file created by xcode (don't forget to let xCode create one if you dont haven't) and put this code :

```
    @implementation NSURLRequest (NSURLRequestCategory)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Create your load request UIWebView normally :

```
webView.delegate = self
let myURL = URL(string: Constants.URL_DOMAINE)
let request = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Enjoyyy :D

Answer (score -2):

edit Info.plist, Add:

1. App Transport Security Settings
2. Allow Arbitrary Loads , value is YES

it's work for me, XCode 7.3