# The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “domain”

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ssh, server

I am trying to fetch JSON from a URL but cannot do so because an error is occuring and therefore response and data are nil.

My code for getting data from URL

```
 loadData(urlString: String, completion : @escaping (Player,Player) -> Void) -> Void {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!){data,response,error in
        if error != nil{
            print("problem in loading data");
            print(error.debugDescription);
        } else{
            let players = self.parseJson(data: data as NSData?)

            let priority = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
            priority.async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(players.0, players.1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume();
```

And the Debug description of the error is as follows with the details of App Transport Security in info.plist -
[image: Image showing info.plist and error.debugDescription]

And the image of code I a using for getting the data from JSON URL.
[image]

Comment: Something is wrong with your server. You should add more specific keywords related to `SSL`, `SSH` and `server`. I have many apps (even on store) which are interacting directly to IP address without any issue.

Comment: @HarvantS. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: He probably can't because it's unclear what the problem is. You will need to look at the certificate your server is sending. Maybe open a page on the server in a browser and see whether the browser has anything to say about the certificate

Comment: I am totaly agree with @Pekka웃.

Comment: @Pekka웃 , I don't have any issues in opening the URL in my browser it is showing JSON without any error or problem.

Comment: Are you accessing it through HTTPS in your browser?

Comment: @Pekka웃 , yes I am accessing through HTTPS in my browser and it is working fine. but I also tried with HTTP and when I do so it gives 404 Not Found The requested URL /test.json was not found on this server.

Comment: @HarvantS. , https://test.wowjust.watch/test.json is teh URL can you help me out.

Comment: @Pekka웃 , https://test.wowjust.watch/test.json is the URL can you help me out now?

Comment: Site does not have valid certificate. Ask your server admin for it. Site is unsafe for browsing. Even google chrome is not allowing me to enter.

Comment: @HarvantS. , I am appyling for the intern and I told this to the company and they told me that this is possible and this is the part of the problem. I am struggling for days on this.

Comment: Ask them to open the URL and check the certificate status via `Inspect Element`.

Comment: When I open the site in the browser I'm getting a certificate warning in Safari. It appears the certificate is issued for `dev2.wowjust.watch`. You would probably need a certificate that is valid for the `test.` host name.

Comment: so, do you have any idea @Pekka웃 what can be done on my hand because I don't have access to anything that is server side.

Comment: Getting iOS apps to ignore certificate warnings and such is difficult, and they get stricter with every version. Not sure what the current status is. Here is some discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876602/swift-2-xcode-7-0-cannot-access-https-site-with-unstrusted-ssl-certificate then maybe you can use a non-https connection for the time being? That requires a special setting in infoplist and is possible only until the end of this year, though, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLSessionDelegate

[image]

You need to add proper session configuration

[image]
Implement
 `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler`

[image]

Comment: This handler just accepts any server certificate. Maybe that's fine for testing, but otherwise it's a security issue.